# JQuery: Store JSON results in a JavaScript array?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, arrays, json

I have a PHP script which creates a JSON array called 'cities'.

I can retrieve data from that using the following JQuery:

```
$.ajax({
  dataType: "json",
  url: "mysql.php",
  success: function(data){

    console.log(data[0]);//Returns first item in cities array

};
```

But I am unsure how to loop through the data retrieved and enter it into a JavaScript array.

I dont really have anyway of initialising a count, such as:

```
var counter = cities.length;
```

it doesnt seem to recognised 'cities; is the name of the retrieved JSON array.

Am I missing something in my ajax script?

Comment: Did you try `data.length`?

Comment: What does it return when you use `console.log(data)`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [I have a nested data structure / JSON, how can I access a specific value?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922383/i-have-a-nested-data-structure-json-how-can-i-access-a-specific-value)

Comment: data is the JSON response, data[0] returns the first item, so... data.length should give you the length

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$.ajax({
dataType: "json",
url: "mysql.php",
success: function(data){

$.each(data.info , function() { //refer to the Json object to address the actual names

    var cityname = this.cityname;

                       });

};
```

Answer (score 2):

If what you get back is a JSON array, you could convert that into a JS array using the `JSON.parse` method.

```
$.ajax({
  dataType: "json",
  url: "mysql.php",
  success: function(data){
    var cities = JSON.parse(data);
    console.log(cities.length);
};
```

If it's just an array of strings, you wouldn't even need to do a `JSON.parse`, because JSON is nothing but a stringified representation of JavaScript object notation. But `JSON.parse` would help convert a JSON to its corresponding JavaScript object notation for *any* valid JS objects.

Answer (score 0):

In the success callback have you tried;

```
success: function ( data ) {
    for ( var index = 0; index < data.length; index++ ) {
        console.log( data[ index ] );
    }
}
```